# When should I use GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, group-by, where-clause

According to  documentation:

> Aggregate functions often need an added GROUP BY statement.

Well, I have a query which is containing an aggregate function:

```
select col1, count(col2)
from table
where col1 = 'anything'
group by col1;
```

Now, my question is: `group by` in the above query is useful or useless? Because there is `where` clause, and I think it does not need to `group by` anymore. Am I wrong?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What are you trying to achieve

Comment: @Drew look at that query and tell me `group by` is needed or it  is vain?

Comment: Group by not needed. As you have already filtered out the rows of that particular group.

Comment: @Code-Monk Thanks, I think like you too. I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: It is better to group by if you are using an aggregate function like count or sum.  You may get away without it in this case in MySQL, but other versions of SQL would throw an error

Comment: Result of this query with and without `group by` will be different, if no row will match `col1 = 'anything'` condition.

Comment: @PetSerAl But I think the output will be the same exactly.

Comment: @stack If you use aggregate function without `group by` then you will get exactly one row in result, even if table is empty or no matching rows. If you use `group by`, then you will get one row for each group, so you will get zero rows, if you have zero groups (no match rows).

Comment: @PetSerAl Ah ...! Good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by is used with aggregating functions, like count.

In your example group by is not needed, because you are restricting your results only to one value, so your select is equal to:

```
select count(*)
from table
where col1 = 'anything';
```

But if you remove your where filter:

```
select col1, count(col2)
from table
group by col1;
```

You will see how many rows, have distinct `col1` value. So it will run your first select for every `col1` value.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
select count(*) as theCount
from table
where col1 = 'anything';
```

If I am reading the tea leaves correctly. Glad to delete Answer (we get 5 a day :) )

### Schema

```
create table t9
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    col1 varchar(10) not null,
    col2 varchar(10) not null
);

insert t9 (col1,col2) values ('a','b'),('a','b'),('a','c'),('b','z');
```

### A few queries

```
select count(*) as theCount 
from t9 
where col1 = 'a';
+----------+
| theCount |
+----------+
|        3 |
+----------+

select count(col2) as theCount 
from t9 
where col1 = 'a';
+----------+
| theCount |
+----------+
|        3 |
+----------+

select count(distinct col2) as theCount 
from t9 
where col1 = 'a';
+----------+
| theCount |
+----------+
|        2 |
+----------+

select col1,count(*) as theCount 
from t9 
group by col1 
order by col1;
+------+----------+
| col1 | theCount |
+------+----------+
| a    |        3 |
| b    |        1 |
+------+----------+

select col1,count(*) as theCount 
from t9 
where col1='a' 
group by col1 
order by col1;
+------+----------+
| col1 | theCount |
+------+----------+
| a    |        3 |
+------+----------+
```

Comment: You have used `count()` (aggregate function) without `group by`. do you need to edit or still you are believe your query is fine? Also it should be noted that I need to `col1` in the `select` statement.

Comment: @stack: we can use count function without group by too, but in this case you will get only record. All these things depends on output you want to get :)

Comment: @stack you already know that col1 = anything (assuming it does), so you don't need it in your select. That said, in general, I think it's good practice to include a group by clause, even where mysql would forgive its omission

Comment: @Strawberry What do you men of *"even where mysql would forgive its omission"*?

Answer (score 0):

You are, without the Group By statement the output of count would be 1 always and you would get a record for each ocurrence.

Group by along with the WHERE in your case, matches all records where col1 = "anything", groups them together and then counts the amount of records grouped.

Comment: What is mean of `groups them together` ?

Comment: Let's say the query matches 5 records, if you don't group them by some field, count will not work as you will get the typical error: "Column 'X' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

That means that to use count(), you need to group together all the records you want to count by a field.